# Drupal 7 and Display suite: How do I override the node title value?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have added a text field (field_title_alt) to a node type.

If the field_title_alt is edited, I want to replace the value of the default node title with the value of field_title_alt.

I have tried the following:

preprocess_node
hook_node_view
hook_node_load

The problem is that when I try to override $node->title, the value is not changed when being outputtet. I have access to the title in the $node->content, but it has markup. I only want to replace the value.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be in `hook_preprocess_node()` but you shouldn't set `$node->title` as the title has already been set up in the template vars. Try this:

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if ($a_condition) {
    $vars['title'] = 'A new title';
  }
}
```